# How to handle long text UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout

I have a view which has a lot of labels. Some of them get the text set dynamically. Sometimes the text is to long to display it within one line. I know how i can display the text in multiple lines. My problem is that when i do display the text in multiple lines then the margins are broken between the labels. Sometimes a label even swapes into the content of the next label.

I want to avoid fixing this "by hand" (repositioning of all other elements). Maybe Autolayout can fix this, but sadly i'm not able to use it for now. But it would be a good argument to convert my project from springs&struts into autolayout. However, maybe there is another way to fix this issue. Would be nice if somebody can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: AutoLayout *can* fix this by specifying fixed vertical spacing between your labels. If you have access to Xcode 5, I'd recommend switching to AutoLayout; if you are stuck with Xcode 4... well this is more debatable.

Comment: Sadly for now i'm stuck with Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` to calculate the height which will be required by each of the labels. You should use this in a loop which iterates over each label in the order they should appear on screen. As you go, increment the `y` position by the height of the current label and the margin. Each label will now have the correct position and at the end of the loop`y` will hold the full required height.

Comment: This seems like an acceptable way. However i don't like the dependency between the code knowing the order of the ui elements. If i change the ordering i have to remember that i also have to adapt my code. But i don't know any better way without Autolayout so probably this is the way to go.

Comment: You could add tags to the labels and sort on that. You could use `IBOutletCollection` to create the array.